# the openness of the union of two disconnected sets (one of which is open and the other one is closed)

Tags: general-topology

Now we have two disconnected sets in complex plane, one of which is open and the other one is closed. Is the union of these two sets open?

Answer (score 2):

Given this level of generality, no. Take for instance $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,|\mathscr{R}(z)|>1\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}$. Then $A$ is open, $B$ is closed, both $A$ and $B$ are disconnected and $A\cup B$ is neither open nor closed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!